# MongoDB Oplogs size increases rapidly

Tags: mongodb

We have MongoDB 4.2.11 with 3 Nodes in replica set - Primary, Secondary and Arbiter.
With a recent incidence in Production, we had Primary node down which caused the Secondary Node to become primary. However in about 5hours the oplog collection almost rose to 15GB causing no free disk space for the current Primary Node. Eventually MongoDB Primary crashed due to no disk space issue.

Question: Is there any way to limit Oplog space in MongoDB 4.2.11? Or the only way forward is to upgrade MongoDB to 4.4 and above.

Here is the link to documentation that clarifies no way to limit oplog in 4.2.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/tutorial/change-oplog-size/

Hope to hear some feedback or any old thread that addresses this. Thanks.

Comment: Does your application run any DDL? E.g. rename a collection, create index, etc.

Comment: No @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0):

You can disable majority commit point check, so the oplog will not grow above the limit. Set `replication.enableMajorityReadConcern` to false (true by default) in the config, or `--enableMajorityReadConcern=false` in the command line.

Please read https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/configuration-options/#replication.enableMajorityReadConcern and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/read-concern-majority/#disable-read-concern-majority to understand consequences. TL;DR version - it's not recommended if you value your data.

Comment: Should be noted, in MongoDB version 5 and higher, you cannot disable MajorityReadConcern anymore. You may follow [Mitigate Performance Issues with PSA Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/tutorial/mitigate-psa-performance-issues/). Command [rs.reconfigForPSASet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/rs.reconfigForPSASet/) does not exist in MongoDB 4.x, however, this command is just a shortcut for setting `{ votes: 1, priority: 0 } and { votes: 1, priority: <num> })`